# How can I exclude an application from Dash search?

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, .desktop

I have an application that I'd like *not* to show up when I search for it is Dash. How can I keep the application, but prevent it from being found when I search for it?

Comment: Have you tried moving the launcher out of /usr/share/applications?

Comment: when I try to do that, it tells me permission not allowed even though I am admin

Comment: You may be an admin, but in Ubutnu (unlike Windows xp), you need to use sudo to do things outside the home dir. For example, `sudo mv /user/share/applications/some-name.desktop /opt`.

Comment: Wait Mike, can you tell me what that command means and how I should edit it to fit Steam?

Comment: See the answer below.

Comment: No need to do anything with sudo. will post an answer in a minute.

Comment: *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, would you be so kind to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.

Comment: @ARS That command means: `sudo` = `Switch User and DO`, `mv` = `move` that file to `/opt` = a place where the Dash does *not* look for apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the Steam Launcher out of /usr/share/applications, and place it into /opt, use the following command:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop /opt/
```

The launcher should still work if you navigate to /opt and doubleclick it. An update of Steam will probably put a new launcher into /usr/share/applications.

For more info on what `mv` does, see `man mv`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to make any changes that need `sudo`

#### How to prevent an application to show up in Dash

- Copy the corresponding `.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`:

  ```
    cp /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
  ```
- Open the local copy with `gedit`:

  ```
    gedit ~/.local/share/applications/steam.desktop
  ```
- Add the following line to the head section of the file (before the line, starting with `Actions=`)

  ```
    NoDisplay=true
  ```
- Save the changes, cLose the file, ***log out and back in*** and you're done.

#### To undo

Simply remove the (local) file `~/.local/share/applications/steam.desktop`

#### Explanation

In general, it is considered bad practice to edit *global* `.desktop` files. Not only will changes effect all users, but if you fail, the file will be irreplaceable.

A local copy of the file however will (after log out/in) will overrule the global one. Also possible updated launchers in `/usr/share/applications` will be overruled without further measures.

The line `NoDisplay=true` will prevent the application to appear in Dash/the Unity Launcher

Comment: Okay so I got up until the 3rd step. Where do I put the "Action" thing or whatever?

Comment: @ARS The `Actions=` line already exists in the file. You need to add the line `NoDisplay=true` somewhere *before* that line.

Comment: @ARS do you manage?

Comment: @ARS *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, would you be so kind to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.